# Android - Download XML with list of events daily or when connecting to internet + how to scheduled notifications?

Tags: android, download, notifications, schedule

Here is my code: https://github.com/jonashendrickx/lenovosocial

In the FeedReader.class and GiveawayReader.class I read a XML from my webserver. Does anyone know how to do this on a scheduled basis, daily or hourly? Or trigger to update it when connecting to the internet?

I also want to add a alarm for my upcoming events when they are about to start, or when a giveaway is found or about to expire.

I don't know what to look for since I am probably using the wrong search terms, but came across this in Java API:
 - AlarmManager

Answer (score 0):

Use AlarmManager for dail or hour basis.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, CheckEventService.class);
            PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 1, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), Constants.UPDATE_AFTER_TIME_ELAPSED, pintent);
```

use Boot Receiver Completed if you want alarm manager call after device switch off.

For Intenet Connectivity- use Broadcast Receiver when Internet turn on-

```
 <receiver android:name=".NetworkChanged" >
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

you can write your code inside

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.webkit.WebView.FindListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NetworkChanged extends BroadcastReceiver {

    WifiManager wifiManager;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        Toast.makeText(context, "On Receive calling", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        wifiManager=(WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        int state=wifiManager.getWifiState();
        if(state==WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED)
        {

        }
    WifiInfo wifiInfo=  wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

//            
//        }


    }
}
```